# Open a mail new message window using javascript

Tags: javascript, email

Is it possible to open a new message window with an attachment using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not in a standard web browser environment.

JavaScript has no access to local files. If you aren't talking about local files, then email clients don't provide a web browser accessible interface for adding attachments.

(If you were talking about JScript in a WSH environment, for example, then things would probably be different, but for the sake of this answer I'm going to assume the most common use case.)